# Computing the inverse function

Tags: functions, inverse

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,2]$ be given by $f(x)=x^2+x^4$. 
Determine if f is an invertible function. If it is, compute its inverse. If it is not invertible, provide an argument to support your claim.

I think that $f$ is invertible because the restrictions on the domain and codomain make it bijective, but I am struggling to compute the inverse. Usually, if I was given $y=f(x)$ I would just rearrange to make x the subject and then swap $x$ and $y$, but I don't know how to do that for this example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Completing square

Comment: Setting $y=x^2+x^4$ and solve this equation and Substitute $x^2=t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=f(x)=x^2+x^4$
$$y=(x^2+1/2)^2-1/4$$
$$\sqrt{y+1/4}-1/2=x^2$$
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{y+1/4}-1/2}=x$$
The last step is valid since $x,y\ge0$.
Hence,
$$f^{-1}(y)= \sqrt{\sqrt{y+1/4}-1/2}=x $$

Comment: Thankyou! I never would have thought to complete the square.

Comment: @T.meeley you may accept or upvote this answer if you think it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f'(x)=2x+4x^3\geq0$ it is only zero in $x=0$ on the given domain, hence the function is monotonic and invertible.

Now, to the inversion:

$$f(x)=x^4+x^2 \implies x^4+x^2-f(x)=0 \text{ use quadratic formula }$$
$$\implies  x^2_{1,2}=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4f(x)}}{2}.$$

Can you complete it from here? Note that you can only take the square-root for the positive case of $\pm$.

$$\implies  x_{3,4}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4f(x)}}{2}}.$$

Now use the domain and the image of the function from the beginning to rule out which sign is correct.